# Number of minors of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

Is there a simple way to count how many $k\times k$ minors an $n\times m$ matrix, or an $n\times n$ symmetric or skew-symmetric matrix has?

Answer (score 3):

Given a generical $n \times m$ matrix $A$ you can uniquely identify one minor by choosing $k$ rows and $k$ columns. So you will have that this number is

$$ \left( \begin{matrix}
m\\
k 
\end{matrix} \right) \times
\left( \begin{matrix}
n\\
k 
\end{matrix} \right) $$

If you study instead a symmetric matrix $n \times n$ you may want to identify $$ A^{i_1, \ldots, i_k}_{j_1, \ldots, j_k} = A_{i_1, \ldots, i_k}^{j_1, \ldots, j_k} $$

In this case, we first count the number of matrix *without* this identification, wich is from previous computation $ \binom{n}{k}^2 $.
We then observe that the minors $A^{i_1, \ldots, i_k}_{i_1, \ldots, i_k}$ are counted once, while $A^{i_1, \ldots, i_k}_{j_1, \ldots, j_k}$, where $\{i_1, \ldots, i_k\} \neq \{j_1, \ldots, j_k\}$ are counted twice. So the answer is
$$ \frac{1}{2} \left[ \binom{n}{k}^2 - \binom{n}{k} \right] + \binom{n}{k} 
= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \binom{n}{k}^2 + \binom{n}{k} \right] $$

Comment: Thank you. What if $A$ is symmetric?

Comment: what would be the difference?

Comment: Some of them appear more the once. I do not want to count two times the same minor. For instance in a $3\times 3$ symmetric matrix we have six $2\times 2$ minors.

Comment: edited. For skew-symmetric matrix it depens on what you wish to identify.